# Sorting of instr() SQL result is not as expected

Tags: mysql

I have a table with primary indexed, when I query:

```
SELECT * FROM `chemical` WHERE name LIKE '%copper%' ORDER BY name ASC
```

The sort is like this:
[image: This is returned by query 1]

If I try another query:

```
SELECT * FROM chemical WHERE name LIKE '%copper%' ORDER BY INSTR(name, 'copper') ASC
```

The result like this:
[image: This is returned by query 2]

I don't really understand why the sorting for second result became that way, at least I expect the name with '(II)' are to be stick together and 'Copper' stay  at the top like this:

This is EDITED JPEG for Illustration.
[image: This is edited JPEG]

My question is:

1) What is the sorting algorithm of the instr() that makes result in second pic?

2) is there any way to query to achieve result like picture 3?

Comment: As per docs *Returns the position of the first occurrence of substring substr in string str. This is the same as the two-argument form of LOCATE(), except that the order of the arguments is reversed.*

Comment: What is the logic behind the expected ordering in the third picture?  If you can't articulate that, then we can't write a query.

Comment: @Michal The OP should include this information as _text_, not as images.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the third picture is not returned from query, it was JPEG edited by me to make an example. If I manage to get that result from SQL the I wouldn't have ask this question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We generally prefer all examples, both real and desired, to be shown as text rather than images. This is so we can try your examples, and so your question remains usable even if the image server goes away. It's easy to format text as data: indent it four lines. That's **much** easier than editing JPEG files, too.

Comment: Ok..understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`INSTR()` returns a number, showing the position in the string where the substring begins.  So, `INSTR('Copper', 'Copper')` and `INSTR('Copper (II) Sulfate', 'Copper')` both return 1.  So, rows with those items will be sorted as if they were identical. MySQL, and all DBMS systems, sort identical items in unpredictabable order.

You may want `ORDER BY INSTR(name, 'copper') <> 1, name` . This will put the names starting with `Copper` first, and otherwise sort the names in alphabetical order.  Why does this work?

```
 input                   ----------------sort keys----------
 name                   INSTR(name, 'copper') <> 1     name 
 Copper                 0                              Copper   
 Copper (II) Oxide      0                              Copper (II) Oxide
 AAS Standard Copper    1                              AAS Standard
 Vanadium Oxide         1                              Vanadium Oxide
```

In ORDER BY clauses, MySQL interprets Boolean values as 0 and 1. `INSTR('Vanadium Oxide', 'Copper')` returns `0` and `INSTR('AAS Standard Copper', 'Copper')` returns 14, so `INSTR('AAS Standard Copper', 'Copper') <> 1` returns false (0).

Comment: @O.Jones hey it works! But what does the     <> 1  ASC did?, Didn't know got such a writing...

Answer (score 1):

sort by the name too so ties are ordered alphabetically:

```
ORDER BY INSTR(name, 'copper') ASC, name
```

this will be different to ojones answer because it moves the earliest copper instances earlier in all cases not just those names beginning with the word.